# Change radio model on button click [angularjs]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

What i want to achieve is trigger the change of the model "value" of the radio  when i click on the button change input. 
Why do i need to call twice click so that the model gets updated and the radio gets checked?

http://jsfiddle.net/7GfB9/

HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="value" ng-value="33">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="value" ng-value="22">{{ value }}
    <button onclick="changeInput()">Change input</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
function Ctrl($scope) {

}

function changeInput() {
    $('input:eq(0)').click().click();
}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and angularjs?

Comment: @Satpal Let's assume i don't know the first input has the value 33 but i still want to check it and update the model how would you do it ? Only way i could make it work is by doing something like $scope.value = $('input:eq(0)').val()

Comment: I will do it something like, http://jsfiddle.net/7GfB9/4/ As you problem is not clear to me. This is a guess

Comment: @Satpal But the problem is that in my real code i don't know what those values are so the only way is to use jquery to get it.

Comment: I think I am getting you. correct me If I am wrong, Initially `value` can have any value and you want to select first radio button as checked

Comment: @Satpal Correct it's actually a dynamic value depending on different situations

Answer (score 0):

Likely because the value is updated before your onclick function is called. Why don't you update the value in your onclick function and only use one click?

Answer (score 0):

Forget jQuery and try this :

```
<button ng-click="value = 33">Change input</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7GfB9/3/

Comment: In this example you could hardcode it like that but in my real code it's alot more dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Solution i've come up with. I'm new to angularjs seems like im not used to it yet.

HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="value" ng-value="33">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="value" ng-value="22">{{ value }}
    <button ng-click="changeInput()">Change input</button>
</div>
```

js

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.changeInput = function () {
        $scope.value=$('input:eq(0)').val();
    }    
}
```

Comment: This will always give to first radio button value

Comment: @Satpal i use an id in my real code application so that it only gets the one from the container i want.